# how do i know how much time took the whole page loading time in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, timestamp, html

i currently use the context.timestamp function to get the time in the beginning of the request but i want to know if i can check the time sooner in the pipeline (before the load page phase) or the timestamp is the earlier time i can get. now i need to find the latest time after the request was processed, of course i can check the time in the end of the function, but is there somewhere else where i can check the time of the request ending.

thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also tap into the IIS pipeline more directly by adding event handlers in Global.asax.  You could handle `BeginRequest` and `EndRequest` for example, which occur well before and well after your Page handler is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just adding a `<%@ Page Trace="true" %>` into your page is enough.

Please, take a look into [ASP.NET Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Because sometimes the `Trace="true"` doesn't work nicely with CSS, you can also, check this page : [Show page load time](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/show-page-load-time/), which has a very detailed explanation (and various different ways) on how to do this.